# Sample 3D points (X,Y,Z) on the surface of a cube using poisson sampling in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, sampling

I am trying to perform Poisson sampling on the faces of a cube in python.

I am new to python, so I found this implementation of Poisson sampling on a plane 
https://github.com/IHautaI/poisson-disc/blob/master/poisson_disc.py

This is what I came up with:

```
    import numpy as np
    import random
    nPoints = 100
    r = 1/np.sqrt(nPoints/6)
    length = 1
    width = 1
    grid = Grid(r, length, width)
    rand = (random.uniform(0, length), random.uniform(0, width))
    PointsBottom = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    Pointstop = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    PointsRight = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    PointsLeft = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    PointsFront = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    PointsBack = np.array([list(elem) for elem in grid.poisson(rand)])
    X = np.concatenate([PointsBottom[:, 0], Pointstop[:, 0], PointsLeft[:, 0], PointsRight[:, 0], np.zeros(len(PointsFront[:, 0])), np.ones(len(PointsBack[:, 0]))])
    Y = np.concatenate([PointsBottom[:, 1], Pointstop[:, 1], np.zeros(len(PointsLeft[:, 0])), np.ones(len(PointsRight[:, 0])), PointsFront[:, 0], PointsBack[:, 0]])
    Z = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(PointsBottom[:, 0])), np.ones(len(Pointstop[:, 0])), PointsLeft[:, 1], PointsRight[:, 1], PointsFront[:, 1], PointsBack[:, 1]])
```

It works fine. My question is - is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean better as in faster, or better as in easier to read / maintain, e.g. with less repetition?

Comment: I meant easier to read and with less repetition but if you have something faster it is also welcomed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review Stack Exchange.